# Haskell: thread blocked indefinitely in an STM transaction

Tags: multithreading, haskell, stm

Is there any way to increase a time interval, on the basis of which the RTS decides that thread has blocked indefinitely in an STM transaction?
Here is my code:

```
import Control.Concurrent (ThreadId)
import Control.Concurrent.MVar (MVar,newMVar,withMVar)
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import qualified Control.Concurrent.ThreadManager as TM

data ThreadManager = ThreadManager { tmCounter::TVar Int, tmTM::MVar TM.ThreadManager }

data Settings = Settings {
    maxThreadsCount::Int }

createThreadManager :: Settings -> IO ThreadManager
createThreadManager s = do
    counter <- atomically $ newTVar (maxThreadsCount s)
    tm <- TM.make >>= newMVar
    return $ ThreadManager counter tm

forkManaged :: ThreadManager -> IO () -> IO ThreadId
forkManaged tm fn = do
    atomically $ do
        counter <- readTVar $ tmCounter tm
        check $ counter > 0
        writeTVar (tmCounter tm) (counter - 1)
    withMVar (tmTM tm) $ \thrdmgr -> TM.fork thrdmgr $ do
        fn
        atomically $ do
            counter <- readTVar $ tmCounter tm
            writeTVar (tmCounter tm) (counter + 1)
```

**forkManaged** makes sure that amount of simultaneously running managed threads does not exceed **maxThreadsCount**. It works fine until heavy load. Under heavy load RTS throws an exception. I think under heavy load, on hard concurrent competition for resources, some of threads just have no time to get access to the STM context. So I think, increasing time interval when RTS decides to throw this exception may solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that decision is made with timeouts? I thought it used its logs to decide when two `retry`s were waiting on each other.

Comment: @Daniel: Daniel, I've updated the question by providing my code using STM. This is why I think the problem with timeout.

Comment: Is it possible that `fn` is throwing an exception, and preventing the counter from being incremented?

Comment: @Daniel: Am I correct, if an exception had being raised, and was not caught in my code, then I should see it in console? Actually those *fn* makes some actions in IO, but these actions are wrapped into *Control.Exception.catch*, and I have not see any complaints in console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Daniel Wagner is right. The decision is not made with timeouts. The relevant code in the rts is in [`Schedule.c`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/53b63e3034e280cd440e75a2a5ab35742263378e/rts/Schedule.c#2400)

See the `resurrectThreads` function for where the exception is thrown. The comment describes that this is only thrown to threads found to be garbage after GC. ezyang described how this worked for mvars: http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/07/blockedindefinitelyonmvar/

[bad speculation concerning `check` removed when I checked its source and realized that it was just a simple guard/retry and not what was described in an earlier paper -- oops! I now suspect that Daniel Wagner is correct here as well, and the issue is somehow that the counter isn't being incremented.]

Comment: Sclv, Daniel, thank you for response, especially for useful links to ghc's rts implementation! I'll check my code once again.