# How to handle or avoid BlockedIndefinitelyOnSTM exception?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, stm

I spent quite a lot of time troubleshooting an issue I had in the application I am working on. This application is a web app, exposing REST endpoints using scotty. It uses a `TVar` to hold its state which is updated through `STM a` actions triggered by the front-end layer.

As this application is based on event sourcing principles, any event generated by business layer *after*  STM transactions complete is stored into an `EventStore` (currently a simple flat file...). Here is the relevant code fragment:

```
newtype (EventStore m) => WebStateM s m a = WebStateM { runWebM :: ReaderT (TVar s) m a }

  deriving (Functor,Applicative,Monad, MonadIO, MonadTrans, MonadReader (TVar s))


    applyCommand :: (EventStore m, Serializable (Event a)) =>
                    Command a                                    
                 -> TVar s
                 -> WebStateM s m (Event a) 
    applyCommand command = \ v -> do
      (e, etype :: EventType s) <- liftIO $ atomically $ actAndApply v
      storeEvent e etype
      return e
      where
        actAndApply =  \ v -> do
          s <- readTVar v
          let view = getView s
          let e  = view `act` command
          let bv = view `apply` e

          modifyTVar' v (setView bv)

          return (e, getType view)
```

This works perfectly, until a bug slipped in the `storeEvent` function. This function is responsible for serialising the event with the appropriate type, and I made a (gross) mistake in my serialisation routine for some type which lead to an infinite loop! Then all of a sudden, my `cabal test` began to hang and fail with a timeout (I use wreq as client library to test REST services). It took me a couple of hours to pin down the actual error on the server side: `tests: thread blocked indefinitely in an STM transaction`. Suspecting the serialisation routine, it took me another couple of hours to nail down the culprit and fix the issue.

Although I am of course entirely responsible for the error (I should have tested more thoroughly my serialisation routine!), I found it quite misleading. I would like to understand better where this error comes from and how to prevent it. I have read [Edward Yang's](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/07/blockedindefinitelyonmvar/) post on the the subject, and [this mail thread](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Avoiding-BlockedIndefinitelyOnSTM-exceptions-td5752644.html) but I must confess the logical chain of events leading to observing this error is not entirely clear to me.

I think I understand the thread calling `applyCommand`, which is spawned by scotty, dies from some exception (stack exhausted?) launched while evaluating `storeEvent`, but I do not understand how this is related to the transaction being *garbage*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception *says* that one thread tried to do a transaction, and hit `retry`, which will rerun the transaction when something changes. But the thing it's waiting for changes on is no longer referenced anywhere, so the retry can *never* happen. And that's a bug. Basically that thread is hung now.

I would *imagine* that some thread somewhere was *supposed* to update this `TVar`, but it died because of an exception, thereby dropping the last reference to that `TVar` and provoking the exception.

That's what I *think* happened. Without seeing the entire application, it's difficult to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I can understand that if the 'main' thread dies then the `TVar` is no longer referenced, however what I do not understand is where the `retry` is supposed to be. I do not use `retry` in my code explicitly, so this must be implicit...

Comment: Do you use `TChan` or something? That will use `retry` internally to block until data is available from the channel.

Comment: That's what is puzzling me: I do not use `TChan`, only `readTVar`, `writeTVar`, `modifyTVar'`.

Comment: Reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862372/haskell-thread-blocked-indefinitely-in-an-stm-transaction I see a link to C source code where the exception is thrown, but this does not help me much. Might this have something to do with underlying threading in warp?

Comment: I think that any STM transaction can call `retry` implicitly (but haven't actually checked the code)